# Index Array with function javascript/html

Tags: javascript, html

I have been working on the 'Simon Says' exercise on freeCodeCamp for a while as I fight to find my own understanding of each code structure.

Today I tried an Array Elements object structure that allows you to have a function in an Array.

The results were that the rules of onclick get overruled by index rules:

```
   <body>
     <h2 id="clickNumber">0</h2>
     <button id="red1" onclick="red()"></button>
     <button id="blue1" onclick="blue()"></button>
     <button id="green1" onclick="green()"></button>
     <button id="yellow1" onclick="yellow()"></button>
<script> 
   var simonArr = [];
       simonArr[0] = red();
       simonArr[1] = blue();
       simonArr[2] = green();
       simonArr[3] = yellow();

 function red(){
   setInterval( function(){
    document.getElementById('red1').style.opacity = ".25";
  }, 4000);
 }

  function blue(){
   document.getElementById('blue1').style.opacity = ".25";
  }
 function green(){
   document.getElementById('green1').style.opacity = ".25"
  }
  function yellow(){
   document.getElementById('yellow1').style.opacity = ".25"
 }
   </body>
</html>
```

The functions run automatically without the click, and create the wrong response.

My next step is to figure why this index rule overrides the onclick?

Comment: In the array you are storing function result. Because you are doing ();  you are not storing function itself

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of points to help you get over the hump and understand what's going on with your code.

#### Assigning a Function reference vs. executing a Function

You are attempting to assign a reference to each function (red, blue, etc.) to an index in your 'simonArr' array; however, you are are actually ***executing*** each of these functions and assigning ***the result*** of each function to these indexes.

```
simonArr[0] = red();
```

Executes the function referenced by the name 'red' and assigns the result, which is undefined because the 'red' function doesn't return anything, to the array 'simonArr' at index 0.  The parentheses `()` are what cause the function to execute.

```
simonArr[0] = red;
```

Will do what you intended to do. It will take the function referenced by the name 'red' and assign a reference to the function itself to 'simonArr' at index 0, and it will not execute the function.

#### Why your onclick doesn't appear to be executing

Your 'onclick' code is will work fine, but it doesn't ***appear*** to be working. That's because by the time you click on the buttons your functions (red, blue, etc.) were already called and set the opacity of your buttons to 25% here:

```
var simonArr = [];
   simonArr[0] = red();
   simonArr[1] = blue();
   simonArr[2] = green();
   simonArr[3] = yellow();
```

Remove the parentheses `()` and you will see the intended effects from your button clicks.

#### Modifying your example to help clarify all of this

I have slightly changed your code to demonstrate both of these points:

1. I removed the parentheses from your function calls
2. I changed your onclick handlers to reference your stored function references (see below)
3. I added console logging to help you see when these calls are executed. If you haven't used console logging before I highly recommend it to aid you as you learn.  Check out the developer tools for your favorite browser.

```js
  var simonArr = [];
  simonArr[0] = red;
  simonArr[1] = blue;
  simonArr[2] = green;
  simonArr[3] = yellow;

  function red(){
    console.log('red was executed!');
    setInterval( function(){
      console.log('the delayed function called was executed');
      document.getElementById('red1').style.opacity = ".25";
    }, 4000);
  }

  function blue(){
    console.log('blue was executed!');
    document.getElementById('blue1').style.opacity = ".25";
  }
  function green(){
    console.log('green was executed!');
    document.getElementById('green1').style.opacity = ".25";
  }
  function yellow(){
    console.log('yellow was executed!');
    document.getElementById('yellow1').style.opacity = ".25";
  }
```

```css
  button { padding: 1em; }
  #red1 { background-color: red; }
  #blue1 { background-color: blue; }
  #green1 { background-color: green; }
  #yellow1 { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<button id="red1" onclick="simonArr[0]()">Red</button>
<button id="blue1" onclick="simonArr[1]()">Blue</button>
<button id="green1" onclick="simonArr[2]()">Green</button>
<button id="yellow1" onclick="simonArr[3]()">Yellow</button>
```

#### What's going on within the 'onclick' handlers?

Well, each index of your 'simonArr' array now references one of your functions.  So for example `red` and `simonArr[0]` now reference the same function. So, this statement:

```
red();
```

...and this statement:

```
simonArr[0]();
```

...will do the same thing.  Both reference the same function, and the addition of the parentheses will cause that function to execute.  Hope that all helps out.  Good luck continuing to explore!

Comment: Thank you! I do apologize, just learning concepts will not just help me but others as well. This is the reason why I posted this question. I learned lessons by schools and camps as well as others and they become confused. I actually found out the reason about 20 mins. afterwards yet you put clarity to the execution. I than decide to write down all the mistakes I was making at each problem to help those learn along the way. I hope this doesn't upset anyone, I just place "self console.logs" for others. All those that learn from you thank you!